# Creating a MoreLikeThis query yields empty queries and terms

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to get similar Document of another one . I'm using the Lucene.Net MoreLikeThis-Class to achieve this. For this i seperate my Documents in multiple Fields - Title and Content. Now creating the actual query results in an empty query without interesting Terms.

My could looks like this:

```
var queries = new List<Query>();
foreach(var docField in docFields)
   var similarSearch = new MoreLikeThis(indexReader);
   similarSearch.SetFieldNames(docField.fieldName);
   similarSearch.Analyzer = new GermanAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>(StopWords));
   similarSearch.MinDocFreq = 1;
   similarSearch.MinTermFreq = 1;
   similarSearch.MinWordLen = 1;
   similarSearch.Boost = true;
   similarSearch.BoostFactor = boostFactor;
   using(var reader = new StringReader(docField.Content)){
      var searchQuery = similarSearch.Like(reader);
      // debugging purpose
      var queryString = searchQuery.ToString();  // empty
      var terms = similarSearch.RetrieveInterestingTerms(reader);  // also empty
      queries.Add(searchQuery);
   }
var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
foreach(var moreLikeThisQuery in queries)
{
   booleanQuery.Add(moreLikeThisQuery, Occur.SHOULD);
}
var topDocs = indexSearcher.Search(booleanQuery, maxNumberOfResults);  // and of course no results obtained
```

So the question is:
 **Why there are no Terms / why there is no query generated?**

I hope important thing's be seen, if not please help me to make my first question better :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

The problem was, that i worked on the false directory.
I have different Solutions for creating the index and creating the queries and had a missmatch with the index-location.

So the generall solution would be:
Is your Querygenerating-Class fully initialized? (MinDocFreq, MinTermFreq, MinWordLen, has a Analyzer, set the fieldNames)

Is your used IndexReader correctly initialized?